# Using dcast in R to transform data frame from long to wide format not working

Tags: r, reshape2

I'm trying to transform a data frame from long to wide format using the dcast function.

Here is the starting data frame:

```
convID     var      value
aa         in       1
ab         in       1
aa         id       4/29/2014
ab         id       4/20/2014
aa         it       Impr
ab         it       Impr
aa         ic       Display
ab         ic       Display
ab         in       2
ab         in       2
aa         id       4/25/2014
ab         id       4/24/2014
aa         it       Impr
ab         it       Click
aa         ic       Display
ab         ic       SEM
```

The desired data frame I want is, where the top half of the `id`, `it`, and `ic` correspond to `in=1` and bottom half of the `id`, `it`, and `ic` correspond to `in=2`:

```
convID     in     id           it       ic
aa         1      4/29/204     Impr     Display
ab         1      4/20/204     Impr     Display
aa         2      4/25/204     Impr     Display
aa         2      4/24/204     Click    SEM
```

However I'm not able to get the desired data frame using the dcast function.  I tried many times and the closest I got was the following:

```
dcast(df,convID~var, value.var="value", fun.aggregate=max)

convID     in     id          it       ic
aa         2      4/29/204    Impr     Display
aa         2      4/24/204    Impr     SEM
```

This is obviously not right as it's returning max values of `in`, `id`, `it`, and `ic` and the proper assignments of `in=1` and `in=2` are disregarded.  Additionally, I'm missing half my data.  Any advise would be greatly appreciated!

```
#Here is code to produce the starting data frame:
convID<-c("aa", "ab", "aa", "ab", "aa", "ab", "aa", "ab", "aa", "ab", "aa", "ab", "aa", "ab", "aa", "ab")  
var<-c("in", "in", "id", "id", "it", "it", "ic", "ic","in", "in", "id", "id", "it", "it", "ic", "ic")
value<-c("1", "1", "4/29/14", "4/20/14", "Impr", "Impr", "Display", "Display", "2", "2", "4/25/14", "4/24/14", "Impr", "Click", "Display", "SEM")
df<-data.frame(convID, var, value)
df$value<-as.character(df$value)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `in` is not already a variable in your data frame (I changed the name to `inval` because there are a few weirdnesses associated with trying to use a variable called `in` inside `within`).

I generated `inval` by using `zoo::na.locf` to set the value for each row to the last previously specified value:

```
library(zoo)
df <- within(df,{
    inval <- ifelse(var=="in",value,NA)
    inval <- na.locf(inval)
})
```

This results in:

```
str(df)
## 'data.frame':    16 obs. of  4 variables:
##  $ convID: Factor w/ 2 levels "aa","ab": 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
##  $ var   : Factor w/ 4 levels "ic","id","in",..: 3 3 2 2 4 4 1 1 3 3 ...
##  $ value : chr  "1" "1" "4/29/14" "4/20/14" ...
##  $ inval : chr  "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
```

Then it's easy to `dcast`:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(subset(df,var!="in"),convID+inval~...)
```

Comment: Hmm...I tried running the df<-within(df,{inval...) but I'm getting an error message.  Error in var == "in" : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types

Comment: I suspect that you do *not* actually have a variable called `var` within your data frame, and that it is actually called `variable` (or something else).  There was some inconsistency in your example code posted above, which I believe @Henrik fixed up for you ...

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  So I got the df<-within(df,{inval...) to work, after renaming variable to var.  However when I ran the dcast function, I got the same issue.  How would you run the rest of the dcast function? You wrote: dcast(subset(df,var!="in"),convID+inval~...)

Comment: the code in my answer above works for me as written (copied & pasted) starting from the (edited) example code in your question. Is your `names(df)` exactly equal to `"convID" "var"    "value"  "inval"` ?

Comment: Yes, names(df) equal to "convID" "var"    "value"  "inval".  When I run your dcast function (literally copying and pasting) as dcast(subset(df,var!="in"),convID+inval~...), I get an error message stating: Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length.  So I re-ran the function as dcast(subset(df,var!="in"),convID+inval~var, value.var="value", fun.aggregate=max).  However this doesn't give me the result I'm looking for.  I must be misinterpreting your feedback.

Comment: Just to clarify: if you start a clean R session, then copy and paste the code blocks in your question and my answer above, you get that error?  What are the results of `sessionInfo()` ?  Results of `str(df)` ?

Comment: When I start a new session of R and run the following commands sessionInfo() and str(df), I get the following:

Comment: > sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] reshape2_1.4 zoo_1.7-11  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_3.1.0      lattice_0.20-29 plyr_1.8.1      Rcpp_0.11.1     stringr_0.6.2   tools_3.1.0

Comment: > str(df)
'data.frame': 16 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ convID: Factor w/ 2 levels "aa","ab": 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ var   : Factor w/ 4 levels "ic","id","inval",..: 3 3 2 2 4 4 1 1 3 3 ...
 $ value : chr  "1" "1" "4/29/14" "4/20/14" ...
 $ inval : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...

Comment: it looks like you changed the *factor level* to `inval`, which would mess things up.

Comment: should i change the var class to character?  if you had to write the code starting with my code, how would you do so?  im very confused at this point.  starting code: convID<-c("aa", "ab", "aa", "ab", "aa", "ab", "aa", "ab", "aa", "ab", "aa", "ab", "aa", "ab", "aa", "ab")  
var<-c("in", "in", "id", "id", "it", "it", "ic", "ic","in", "in", "id", "id", "it", "it", "ic", "ic")
value<-c("1", "1", "4/29/14", "4/20/14", "Impr", "Impr", "Display", "Display", "2", "2", "4/25/14", "4/24/14", "Impr", "Click", "Display", "SEM")
df<-data.frame(convID, var, value)
df$value<-as.character(df$value)

Comment: Look carefully at the `$var` value you got. `str()` gives the results `Factor w/ 4 levels "ic","id","inval", ...`.  That's **not** what I get when I run the same starting code you specified here. I get `Factor w/ 4 levels "ic","id","in", ...`.  I don't know how/why you got that result, but that difference is the problem ...

Comment: It worked!  Thank you for being so patient and helping me thoroughly.  I made some edits to the code as I was going along the way, which complicated it.  If you were close by, I'd buy you lunch!  Thanks, again.  -Eric